# How to display data from sqlite in textview

Tags: android

i have a problem... How to display data from sqlite in textview..

please help me out..

Thank u..

Answer (score 0):

i am giving u a simple database table,in which u should define roll no, name , marks
and through roll no u can fetch related data through cursor...

```
private void getStudent() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int roll_no = Integer.parseInt(rollText.getText().toString());

    Cursor c = db.getStudent(roll_no);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        nameText.setText(c.getString(1));
        marksText.setText(c.getString(2));
    }

}
```

create project and call like this function in clickevent...

i think you understand it...

all the best...

Comment: how to display to editText ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161803/retrieve-data-from-sqlite-to-edittext-text-view